# implementing a copy constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I have the following class definition and it needs a copy constructor so deep copies are made to copy the raw pointers.  Can anybody advice on how to best do this?

Using [xerces-c++](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/index.html) for XML

```
class XMLDocument 
 {
 private:
  typedef std::vector<XML::XMLNode> v_nodes;
 public:
  XMLDocument::XMLDocument();
  XMLDocument::XMLDocument(const XMLDocument& copy); 
  XMLDocument::~XMLDocument();

  XMLDocument& operator=(XMLDocument const& rhs);

  void CreateDocument(const std::string& docname);
  void AddChildNode(XMLNode& node);
  void RemoveNode(XMLNode& node);
  void AddNodeValue(XMLNode& node, const std::string& value);
  void AddNodeValue(XMLNode& node, int value);
  void AddNodeValue(XMLNode& node, double value);
  void AddNodeValue(XMLNode& node, float value);
  std::string GetXMLAttributes();
  std::string GetXMLAttribute(const std::string& attrib);
  std::string GetXMLNodeText(XML::XMLNode& node);
  std::string DumpToString();
  XMLNode GetXPathNode(const std::string xpathXpression);
  XMLNode GetNode(const XMLNode &currentnode);

  typedef v_nodes::iterator nodes_iterator;
  nodes_iterator begin()
  {
   nodes_iterator iter;
   iter = xmlnodes.begin();

   return iter;
  }
  nodes_iterator end()
  {
   nodes_iterator iter;
   iter = xmlnodes.end();

   return iter; 
  }


 private:
  v_nodes xmlnodes;

  bool InitializeXML();
  DOMImplementation* impl; //Abstract
  DOMDocument* document; //Abstract
  DOMElement* rootelement; //Abstract

 };
```

The DOMDocument **is created calling a function** and **so is** the DOMElement.  So I can't just call new on these pointers.

Not sure if I just literally recreate all these object?

Example:

```
document = impl->createDocument(0, "mydoc", 0);
```

Who's gone on a downvote rage and not given a reason???

Comment: You should probably mention in your question that you're using this and not your own classes: http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classDOMImplementation.html

Comment: Do the classes in question have a clone() interface of some sort?  If not, you may be SOL if you want to copy the object hierarchy (meaning you'd have to do it manually, either by walking the nodes yourself or by serializing and deserializing the document somehow)

Comment: No clone that I can see, and what does SOL mean?

Comment: With the caveat that it has been a few years since I used it... Beware of memory leaks with Xerces and be very careful how you use memory with it.  I *suspect* the missing copy constructors have something to do with the memory leaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page might certainly help:
http://icu-project.org/docs/papers/cpp_report/the_anatomy_of_the_assignment_operator.html

Note their is a difference between writing a copy-constructor and an assignment operator but this point is also discussed in the paper.

Comment: That page contains only "half the truth", as the author had to find out himself: http://icu-project.org/docs/papers/cpp_report/the_assignment_operator_revisited.html

Comment: @AudioDroid I definitely missed this one. Thank you for the enlightenment.

Answer (score 2):

Writing a copy constructor is always about doing "The Right Thing" for each member variable. Without seeing the API docs for your `DOMImplementation` etc. it is hard to say what "The Right Thing" would be, here. Perhaps there is a copy constructor for them, or a function to make a deep copy. Perhaps you don't *need* a deep copy, semantically (e.g. for `DOMImplementation`).

Bottom line, hard to say without seeing the API docs you surely have lying around...

**Edit:** So you are using Xerces-C. You didn't tell us that before...

**Edit 2:** Let's see, then...

The Xerces-C API indeed does *not* provide any "easy" means of copying a document object, from what I can see. AFAICT, you will have to create a completely new document (`impl->createDocument()`), and then copy over any attributes and child nodes manually.

This being so awkward, I would raise the question "*why* do I want to copy my `XMLDocument` object, anyway? Does it even make sense, on a semantic level?". (Personal experience: If things get ugly while working with a well-used API, chances are you're doing something wrong, because there would be an easy way otherwise. XML is not my strong streak, so I'm out of my depth here.)

Comment: This classes not have copy-constructor.

Comment: @DevSolar: What about passing this XMLDocument object around and returning it from a function by value?  Should I then just always return a pointer? Or a smart_ptr?

Comment: @Tony: I don't really see what you're trying to do here. A wrapper around the Xerces-C API? Xerces-C handles `DOMDocument` objects through pointers, and doesn't allow for (easy) copying of `DOMDocument`s. Unless you have something specific in mind (and the skill to pull it off), you should heed that, and not trying to "force" it into a different behaviour.

Comment: @DevSolar, I just wanted to wrap the complexity of doing standard XML things I need throughout my program in a class and only use the bits from xerces that I need.

Comment: Then my wrapper can be used throughout the rest of my program and if anyone ever decides to change what XML lib to use, the whole program is not affected.

Answer (score 1):

Devsolar is right about copy constructors. Heed his advice.

Furthermore you really shouldn't be copying the DOM structures. Standard procedure when I am working with XML is to write a handler that gets the data from DOM/SAX and builds a native object based off that structure. Once you are done reading all the DOM/SAX elements you should have constructed in memory either:

1. A data structure that holds all the data you needed from the XML.
2. An object built from the XML but decoupled from XML. You use this object within your application. Most likely you will serialize this object **to xml** in the future.

This way you don't need to copy DOM. You instead build native objects to represent the data. Remember you want to decouple your application from XML. What if in the future you decide to use binary serialization?

Comment: Sorry, deleted the copy-constructor comment... it's not always The Right Thing, and I thought it wouldn't be a good *general* advice.

Answer (score 1):

If the deep copying that you want is possible with the library you're using, then the way to go about it is to ensure that every *owned* data member of your class `XMLDocument` knows how to copy itself (using its own copy constructor). And so on recursively for each data member's type. In practice this means defining copyable wrapper types from the ground up.

Take care to define exactly what's owned (to be copied) and what's not (existing elsewhere and just referenced).

The main reason for this hierarchical wrapping is that you want C++'s automatic destruction to kick in when some copying of a part fails. But it also greatly simplifies things. And when you get down to the lowest levels of constituent parts, you may get better advice about copying such a smallest part.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend rethinking the ownership rules a little bit.  If you want to do a deep copy, chances are you are trying to work around what variable owns the memory of other variables.  In your case, it seems like you care about each instance of XMLDocument owning the v_nodes and DOM-related variables.

Another way to resolve the underlying issues is to wrap your instance variables in smart pointers.

In this way, each time you copy construct XMLDocument, you're just bumping the ref count on each of the ivars.  Each time the dtor for an XMLDocument instance gets called, the ref count decrements.  In essence, you're decoupling the lifetime of each XMLDocument instance from its ivars.  Instead, it's the ref count that owns it.

I'm not an expert on xerces, but it's worth checking out various smart ptr implementations, e.g. the boost library.