# C++ copy constructor by pointer

Tags: copy-constructor, pass-by-pointer

Hello i want to create a new class variable that is a pointer and initialize it by copy constructor. Though I know how copy constructor works by refernce, i cannot figure out how to do it. Can you help me?
For example I have this definition:

```
class A{
public:
 int a;
private:
};
```

and in another code segment i do the following:

```
A *object= new A;
A->a=10;

A *newobject= new A(*object);
```

but i get a segmentation fault. Can you help me?
I also tried:

```
 A *newobject= new A(&(*object));
```

but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Please submit a complete, compiling sample.  Foo vs A?  A.a vs object->a?

Comment: [**Works fine**](http://ideone.com/uy1hAk) if you remove out the obvious errors. Important Q is why do you want to do this anyways?

Comment: In order to make a queue withought using STL fully dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this kind of simple example, the following which uses the default bit wise copy constructor works fine.

The simple class looks like

```
class Bclass {
public:
    int iValue;
};
```

And the code to use the copy constructor looks like:

```
Bclass *pObject = new Bclass;
pObject->iValue = 10;

Bclass *pObject2 = new Bclass (*pObject);
```

Using Microsoft Visual Studio 2005, the above works fine.

See also [Implementing a Copy Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088411/implementing-a-copy-constructor).

See also [Copy constructor for pointers to objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546402/copy-constructor-for-pointers-to-objects).

Answer (score 2):

These lines in your example shouldn't even compile:

```
A *object= new A;
A.a=10;
```

What you mean is

```
Foo *object = new Foo;
object->a = 10;
```

Right?

**Edited to add:**

What happens when you try [the code posted](http://ideone.com/uy1hAk) by @Alok Save?

Comment: Yeah i wrote it in rush! The problem is below that!

Answer (score 0):

Since the class name is Foo and not A, a Foo object should be created.

```
class Foo{
  public:
  int a;
  private:
}; 

 Foo *object= new Foo;
 object->a=10;
```

Now since object is a pointer to class Foo, the -> operator should be used.